Screen tearing issue
After installing Ubuntu 24.04.1 on my laptop I'm experiencing screen tearing while watching videos. I've tried different media players, but the issue persists across the board.
System specs:

​Integrated GPU: AMD Radeon 680M

​Discrete GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2050

​Display: 1920x1080 @ 60 Hz


